# CSS Background cover fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

On a PC, the background i have set for the sites background looks fine -- covering the space and fixed in its position to give the wrapper a "hover" effect. However, on a tablet or mobile phone, if the wrapper/content flows past the page, the background is slightly different and has changed -- not completely covering and fixed to the viewport.

How do i combat this?

```
html { 
      background: url(../images/wall2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      min-height:100%;
      min-width:100%;
    }
    body {
        margin:0px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    #wrapper {
        margin:75px auto;
        width:960px;
        background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
        background-repeat:repeat;
    }
    #content {
        color:#000;
        margin-top:0px;
        padding:50px;
    }
```

I've tried adding overflow:hidden to the wrapper and content, but that does not help.

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3C5jX/

Comment: put a fiddle an we will help

Comment: How clumsy -- http://jsfiddle.net/3C5jX/

Thank you

Comment: Media queries u need Media queries for that i guess

Comment: Cannot figure this out. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the height and width to 110%, also try adding the background as a fixed html element rather than a css background.